# How to declare class array in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I can declare `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray` but I want to declare class array. Let say user is a class so I can declare array as:

```
user* obj[10];
```

it is valid in Objective c, but I am not sure how I can set array capacity dynamically. Which we usually do with MutableArray as initWithCapacity:..

This is what I am doing with class:

```
user* objuser;
CustomOutput* output = [[CustomOutput alloc] init];
[objuser cutomSerialize:output];
NSMutableData* data = output.data;
```

But If I have array as:

`NSMutableArray* aryUserObj;`

I can't call `cutomSerialize` method from arryUserObj.

I want to Serialize all the userObj at ones and get a single NSData object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "declaring a class array" (whatever that means) — it has to do with the fact that you need some way to serialize several objects objects together, which would have to be part of the class's implementation, either by allowing the serialization method to build up the serialized data gradually or by giving the class a method that takes an array of instances and uses its serialization logic to do them all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard approach to serialize an array of objects is for you to define `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` in your `User` object:

```
@interface User: NSObject {
 ....
}
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder ;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;
@end
```

What you currently have in `CustomSerialize` should be in these methods.

Then, if you want to encode an object, you do

```
User* user=... ;
NSData* data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user];
```

and decode it:

```
User* user=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

If you have an array of objects,

```
NSMutableArray* array=... ; // an array of users
NSData* data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

and

```
NSArray* array=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Iteration over array is done automatically.
Note also that you don't get the mutable array back, it's an immutable array.

Comment: +1, except that `NSKeyedUnarchiver` does not maintain the mutability of the objects.  IOW, if you archive an `NSMutableArray`, you're going to get an `NSArray` back.  It's kind of lame, but that's how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * users = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; ++i) {
  User * aUser = [[User alloc] initWithStuff:someStuff];
  [users addObject:aUser];
  [aUser release];
}
```

Comment: I know this... but I don't want to use NSMutableArray need to use only class array. Because I have to serialize this class object and I can assess serialize method only in class not from MutableArray. Ex:  obj.serialize(data); This could possible only if I have class obj.

Comment: @iPhoneDev you can still iterate the objects in the array and serialize them, or you can implement the `<NSCoding>` protocol, then just serialize all of the objects at once by serializing the array.

Comment: Yes this I want to serialize all object at ones and send it as NSData. Please let me know how we can use `NSCoding` for this..

Comment: @iPhoneDev read the documentation on Archiving and Serializations and let us know what questions you have: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html